# Divergence in any frame.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given a vector field $X$in $M$, defined along the submanifold $\Sigma$, we can define the tangential divergence of $X$ to be

$$\operatorname{div}_\Sigma X = \sum_{i = 1}^n (\nabla_{e_i} X, e_i)$$

where $e_1, \dots, e_n$ is any orthornomal frame of $\Sigma$

I want to show that for any frame $v_1,\dots,v_n$ for $\Sigma$, we have

$$\operatorname{div}_\Sigma X = \sum_{i,j = 1}^m (v^i,v^j)(\nabla_{v_i} X, v_j)$$

I tried using Gram-Schmidt on $v_1, \dots, v_n$, but it not work. I don't actually know how to define the divergence without trace. I know the result here is summing all possible $(i,j)$ entries in the matrix.

Comment: Be careful about what you mean by $v^i$ here.  It is the dual basis to $(v_i)$, not the musical isomorphism dual.

Comment: In coordinates, divergence of $X$ is defined as $g^{ij}\langle\nabla_i, X,\partial_j\rangle$.

Comment: @Mr.Brown Be careful!  It is the *tangential* divergence on $\Sigma$, not the divergence on $M$.

Comment: Sure, but then you just take the $\partial_i$ to be coordinates on $\Sigma$ no?

Comment: Use $\sum_j(v^i, v^j)v_j= v^i$ to simplify the last equation.

Comment: @tensor_and_manifold To write as $\sum (\nabla_{v_i} X, v^i)$?

Comment: Yes - hope this helps.

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure how rewriting it like this changes anything.